# Trackpad works for Diagnostic Test. Can I rule out it has a hardware problem?

Tags: macbook-pro, trackpad, software

If a MacBook Pro trackpad is able click and scroll, swipe, move cursor, etc. during a during Diagnostic Test (when I  startup holding down the  <kbd>D</kbd>) then, am I able to rule out that it has a hardware problem?

The test results show I have no problem. Its just that during the the test my track pad works.

Comment: Do you have a mouse or a wireless Trackpad connected to your MacBook?

Comment: Yes when I was no longer able to use the trackpad to navigate I started using the Logitech M310 mouse. The trackpad moves as its starting up after I login if I swipe over and over it moves about 4 times. So it seems like what ever is loading at startup has the power when its loaded to prevent the trackpad from scrolling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If a MacBook Pro track pad is able click and scroll, swipe, move
>   cursor, etc during a during Diagnostic Test (when I startup holding
>   down the D key) then am I able to rule out that it has a hardware
>   problem?

For the most part, yes.  It's extremely rare/unlikely that hardware will work fine in one environment, then completely fail in another.  In cases like this, it tends to be a software issue (i.e. conflicts with other software, bad drivers/kexts, mis-configurations, etc.)

Your next step in diagnosing the problem will be to...

- boot into Safe Mode
- boot into Recovery mode
- boot a clean and/or older version of macOS from a different volume (a 16 or 32GB Flash drive is more than sufficient)

The idea with any/all of the above is to get the OS as close to "factory" as possible for testing/diagnostics.  Safe mode isn't always "factory fresh", but Recovery and a clean install on a different volume is.  If you happen to have an older version of macOS you can install on an external volume, then you can evaluate whether it's your newest update that's causing the issue.

Comment: I tested out Safe Mode today and right after Safe Mode started up it acted the same as I explained at regular start up only it did let me move more times and for a longer period of time before it stopped responding. I then did what I thought was a recovery. It was a internet globe recovery and the cursor worked at first, again the same as it did in Safe Mode.  When I was in recovery mode I did a first aid and I looked in the Verify option. Things in there did not seem organized. I would like to start over from what is in there.